# How can i call c# windows form with html submit button?

Tags: c#, html, forms

I have a windows form. And i want to make a login page in html. In hmtl page user should type correct name and password then press button. After submit button i want to open my c# windows form application. How can i handle this issue ?

Login page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Login Screen</title></head>

<form action="?????" method="GET">
UserName: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Password: <input type="text" name="pwd"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</html>
```

And i want to call my frmEntr.cs form. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: What about WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting Property cannot use this method ?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to show an HTML login form, if you have a WinForms application?

Comment: I want to do project which user can login webiste by using my windows application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a windows form application from a browser without plugins. You might want to rethink your design.

Comment: you just say what i was trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a windows form application from a browser. You have to rethink on what you are want to do.

I think you want to perform `login` logic from windows application which is already implemented. all what you need to do is to create a web service with login logic and call it from your web application, Or create Api with authentication logic in it then call it from your web application.

Answer (score 0):

When the client installs the win forms application you need to register an URI scheme to it. Lets say you register "myApp". After the user presses submit you need to simulate an on click on a `<a href="myApp:params">`.

This will be similar to a [`mailto` scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

Read [how to register an uri scheme to an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are trying to have an interaction between javascript code in html and c# code in the container. 
In this case, you should be able to use javascript's window.external.externalMethod() to externalMethod() in c#.

The syntax should be something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="blah" onclick="window.external.externalMethod();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the windows application, you must use the activex. The solution should be like this: [C#制作、打包、签名、发布Activex全过程](http://www.cnblogs.com/still-windows7/p/3148623.html)

Comment: It is better to post English version